# Connect geomarkers from two data layers with lines

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am building a leaflet.js map with two different JSON data layers saved as js-files.

The first data file contains the geolocations of some newsrooms and the newsroom's ID, the second contains the geolocations of some articles as well as the newsroom's ID.

I want to plot these locations and connect all articles with ID X via lines to the newsroom with ID X.

Both data layers are saved as variables. I know how to plot the geolocations, but I can't figure out how to connect the geopoints of layer 2 with the matching geopoints of layer 1 with lines. Any suggestions?

This is what I've done so far:

```
function myFunction() {

 var map = L.map('map').setView([51.101516, 10.313446], 6);
  // improve experience on mobile
  if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();
  L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ',
    maxZoom: 16
}).addTo(map);
  map._layersMinZoom=5; 


for (var i in artikeldaten){
         data = artikeldaten[i];

         L.circleMarker([data.lat, data.long], {
          radius: 4,
          color: '#000',
          fillColor: '#000',
          fillOpacity: 1,
        }).addTo(map)

      } 

for (var i in blogdaten){
         data = blogdaten[i];

   L.circleMarker([data.lat, data.long], {
          radius: 5,
          color: '#000',
          fillColor: '#000',
          fillOpacity: 1,
        }).addTo(map)              
      }
}
```

And this is how the data looks like:

```
    var artikeldaten = [
 {
   "ID": 12,
   "long": 6.7667818,
   "lat": 51.2135308,
 },
 { ... and so on
```

Comment: What's the cardinality of the IDs? Are there several `artikel`s per `blogdaten`, or are there several `blogdaten`s per `artikel`, or something else?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as creating a L.Polyline between your newsroom and each of its articles ? http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#polyline

Comment: there are several artikeldaten per blogdaten! And to Francelmage: I thought so too, but I just can't figure out how to do so automatically because I can't figure out how to loop through two data sources at the same time

Comment: Guess it's a noob question, still a beginner. I have to write some kind of loop that gives me the lat&long from blogdaten[i] matching the ID from artikeldaten[j] first. If I figure that out, I can draw the polylines as explained in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem well, you have to put one of your lists in an associative array first.

```
var newsroomsById = {}; // key: ID

for(i=0; i<newsrooms.length; i++) {
    newsroomsById[newsrooms[i].ID] = newsrooms[i];
}
```

Then you can draw your polylines while you're iterating through yours articles

```
for(i=0; i<articles.length; i++) {
    // retrieve newsroom
    var newsroom = newsroomsById[articles[i].ID];
    // draw your polyline
    var latlngs = [
      [articles[i].lat, articles[i].lng],
      [newsroom .lat, newsroom.lng]
    ];
    var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: This is great! Do you maybe have a suggestion for my next task, too? I'd like to add a click event to the bloglocations where the other blogs get blurred out so you can have a better look at the clicked network. Or the same thing via searching for a specific blog ID with a search bar added to the map. :)

Comment: I'd suggest you open another question. Ideally, put a link to what you have at the moment. I have an example of multiple channels here http://www.franceimage.com/map/?llz=46.566414,2.4609375,6. I'll try and tweak it to show the markers of all channels (which I think is what you want)